# after build and submission I can't run my app on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

even though I select debug, i get this: a valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found
.

i can't install it on my phone again. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mistakenly change the provisioning profile for all builds, rather than just Distribution? Go back into your Project Settings, select Build, and make secure Debug is selected from the Configuration dropdown. Scroll down to Code Signing and check the Code Signing Identity.